# With React, is it possible to have a propType to specify the DOM element type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to create a React UI-Compoment for Typography. Where the component can be passed a propType to specify which element type should be rendered  or

Perhaps a propType used like: `as="span"` or `as="p"`

Is this type of dynamic element type definition possible with React or do I need to do something less elegant and have a Switch statement with two types or return statements?

```
example: `if (this.props.p) {return <p>....</p>}
```

Example using this proposed component:

```
<MyC as="span">Hello World</MyC>
<MyC as="p">Hello World</MyC>
```

Comment: I don't think that there is a provided proptype for each element type. You can however define custom proptypes with a function, check the react docs for an example

Comment: How would the content be passed?

Comment: Content would be passed as children

Comment: @Tony just updated the question with how content would be passed... that's how I'm thinking about, curious to hear your thoughts. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `React.createElement()` as such:

```
class MyC extends Component {
  state = {
    ready: false,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.el = React.createElement(this.props.as, {}, this.props.children);
    this.setState({ ready: true });
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.ready) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.el;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return <MyC as="span">Test</MyC>;
  }
}
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/xozpn8ol9o

Comment: What problem are you seeing? I had it working in `create-react-app`

Comment: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Comment: Did you copy paste? No typos or anything? What version of react?